# Is my unsaved Quicktime player movie recording still on the hard drive somewhere?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, quicktime

I recorded a movie (File > New Movie Recording) using Quicktime Player and when I stopped I accidentally clicked "Don't Save" instead of "Save".

Is that recorded content still on the hard drive somewhere, maybe in a temp or cache folder or something in a hidden directory?

I'd like to recover it.  Thanks.

Comment: Might it be here?: ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Autosave Information/. I didn't see anything in my experiment, but it might be because I didn't leave it going that long.

Comment: @quip Thanks but nothing there. Useful to know, tho. Any other ideas, please shout. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to recover a recording after QuickTime Player crashed because I disconnected the projector which was in full-screen. I found my recording up until the point of crash in this location: `/Users/AB/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Autosave Information/Unsaved QuickTime Player Document.qtpxcomposition`

More info here: https://www.macstories.net/news/recovering-a-lost-quicktime-recording/, which in summary said to:

1. Right-click the qtpx file we found
2. Select "Show Package Contents"
3. Find the movie or audio we were looking for and copy it to where we want

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you can't recover the file, at least at the level of the Finder. However you may be able to by using recovery software (See below as to where the file is temporarily located).

When a QuickTime recording is started using **File : New Movie Recording**, the temporary file sits in the folder:

**~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX.savedState/**

Once the recording is closed, without saving, the file **window_**(some unique number)**.data** is automatically deleted. You can see this if you go to the location above, start a recording, and then close without saving.

Answer (score 1):

thank you Robert Hume

~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Autosave Information/

it's important don't close or reopen Quicktime jut go to that folder and you will see your file

thanks a lot this was so helpful

Answer (score 0):

**For macOS Ventura:**

1. On your Desktop, select `Go`
   [image]
2. When the dropdown list will come, then hold "Option" key on the keyboard
3. Select `Library`
4. Select `ScreenRecordings` folder

`Library/ScreenRecordings`